# Update value in database after done with EditText?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, focus, textwatcher

So I want to have the user be able to change the value of an EditText and update a corresponding value in the database.

So far I've looked into various techniques, but they all have issues.

1. TextWatchers seem to work, but since they trigger after every number/letter press, that seems like a lot of wasteful calls to the database.
2. Focus triggers, but many of the posts I've found are old and possibly outdated, and I don't know if they'll work on all devices.

What is the more recent/up to date fix for this issue? How can I universally detect when an EditText has lost focus and can safely trigger the database call?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   editext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focus) {
 if(focus==false)
 {
     //do database operation
 }
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You may rely on the user pressing 'Done':

   ```
   editText.setOnEditorActionListener(
       new EditText.OnEditorActionListener()
       {
           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction( TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event )
           {
               // you may also use IME_ACTION_SEARCH or
               // event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
               if ( actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE )
               {
                   // update database

                   // consume event
                   return true;
               }

               // don't consume event
               return false;
           }
       }
   );
   ```
2. You may use the TextWatcher approach but in combination with a Timer which pushes an update to the database every - lets say - 2 seconds after the last change has occurred.
   So you simply have to start the Timer on the first change and reset it with every following.

I've encountered this problem myself some time ago but unfortunately I couldn't figure out any other solution that the ones above or the approach with the FocusListener.